# Can we add range as criteria in extracting values from database?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have a query regarding extracting values from sql. Suppose I have date column in my sql db and I want to extract few rows in specific date range. How to write a query for that?

```
sql = "DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE AGE > '%d'"
        cursor.execute(sql, (AGE,))
```

That above query would delete for age > the entry but I want to have for dates here in string format and I want from specific date to another specific Date.

Answer (score 0):

Use python to get the data string into a datetime object and then:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DOB BETWEEN %s AND %s"
cursor.execute(sql, (datetime.strptime("30-09-1966","%d-%m-%Y), datetime.strptime("30-09-2019","%d-%m-%Y)))
```